# Is it Possible to display content of h:selectOneMenu horizontally

Tags: jsf-1.2

I want to display Dropdown like 1 2 3 4 5. Below is my code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="yearFilterSelectOneMenu" value="#{eventMaster.yearFilter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{eventMaster.yearSelectItemsList}" />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{eventMaster.searchByMonthAndYear}"
        render="things_to_render" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved with CSS and h:selectOneRadio
follow below link and everything will be perfect.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/css-radio-button-checkbox-background/ .

JUST CHANGE h:selectOnEMenu to h:selectOneRadio and apply above mention css to it.